# Change default sort order when sort order value is not used

Tags: sorting, magento-1.9

In Magento categories it is possible to set "sort order" values on products (in Admin, Categories), to display certain products beforen others (products with lower value displays first). However; when the value is identical on all items Magento will by default display the oldest items first (low product ID).

Is it possible to change this so that newest items display first instead?

PS: I'm not talking about changing the category sorting to "sort by creation date" or similar. But as an example; let's say you have "sort by price" and 10 products with same price; I would then like the newest items to display first – and not the oldest first (which is default when sort order value is identical on all items).